# Why did django 1.9 change my button styles?

Tags: css, django, compass, django-1.9

I am trying out updating from Django 1.8.4 to Django 1.9.1.

I have had an [application](http://childhealth.maventy.org) working for years.  The original styling was done by somebody else years ago, and we used [Compass](http://compass-style.org/).  I had to port from Google app engine to Heroku, and due to time constraints had to drop Compass, so I am working from old pre-computed CSS files.

When I change the Django version, my buttons completely change how they look.

Old:

[image: Old button]

New (I don't like it):

[image: New button]

Why did this change, and how can I fix it?

P.S. No errors in server-side logs or Chrome debugging console.  I looked at the styling in the Chrome tools, but I can't spot a difference.  There are hundreds of lines of styling (inherited from, inherited from, ..) so I may have missed something.

**Edit 1**: I just pushed the Django 1.9.1 version to the production site, and the buttons still look fine. I don't know why they look weird in my dev environment, but now I am not going to worry about it.

Also, someone advised I post a truly reproducible example.  That is good advice, but I know little enough about the problem that it would take a long time to figure that out.  Given it seems to be okay in production I'm going to punt.

I am in the uncomfortable position of not being able to accept an answer because I didn't figure out what happened, but I bet it has to do with the flat styling mentioned below.

So, thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Does it look different in other browsers as well?

Comment: Huh, aren't you clever. It looks fine in Firefox 44.0, broken in Chrome 48.0.2564.97. I hate web development so much. This is on OS X if it matters.

Comment: This looks like a pure css issue. If you want help fixing it, you have to post a link or add a [mcve]

Comment: Is the button styled at all? Im thinking that maybe the styling of a default button has changed in chrome...

Comment: Anyhow, in django 1.9 the admin has got a flat styling, you can read the release notes here... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/

Comment: Maybe you have to rebuild the style sheets with compass? The text looks the same, but the button is different. If you don't know any css/compass, you should probably ask someone who does to help you. There are almost an infinite possible reasons why the styling is not as you expect it, and it's impossible to know why from only a screenshot.

Comment: Is it possible your browser is just holding a cached version? Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: @Sayse: Good question. I tried reloading without caching, and it still looks okay. What I did: opened the 'network' tab in chrome, clicked "disable cache" and refreshed the page. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/34935. Still, maybe you're right and I'll see it later somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Django admin, in Django 1.9, the admin has got a new flat look.

> New styling for contrib.admin
>   The admin sports a modern, flat design with new SVG icons which look perfect on HiDPI screens. It still provides a fully-functional experience to YUI’s A-grade browsers. Older browser may experience varying levels of graceful degradation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/

Comment: This is not on the admin screens, it's on the screens of the app itself. However, I wonder if the person who styled it used the admin stylings for the app itself. I don't know how I would tell. Also, why would that happen in chrome but not Firefox?

Comment: is the link accessible for us without login? The buttons I can find on your page looks like the old buttons in your post for me, im using chrome on os x

Comment: I just pushed the Django 1.9.1 version to the production site, and the buttons still look fine. I don't know why they look weird in my dev environment, but now I am not going to worry about it. Thank you for your help!